# How to disable PIN on SIM card

Tags: 11.10, gnome, network-manager, 3g, mobile-broadband

My SIM card is stuck inside the slot of my laptop and I can't get it out without causing further damage to my laptop.

Every time I log in gnome-shell prompts me for the PIN. Whether I am about to use it or not.

On my phone I know I can disable the PIN altogether so that it doesn't get requested again (even if place the SIM card on another device). How can I do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't have a piece of hardware like this on my computer to test with. Do you know the name of the daemon that is prompting for your password? Try `sudo pstree` while it is present and looking for something that might look like it. From there we might be able to alter it's config, uninstall it, or disable the hardware

Comment: This is [bug #704123](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/704123) marked as `fix released'. As a bug report this is off topic here.

Comment: @Takkat, how is this a bug-report? I am asking for a workaround. I am on 11.10

Comment: @Huckle I suppose that would be NetworkManager.

Comment: @d_inevitable: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs

Comment: @Takkat I am not informing about a bug. I know the bug exists and I know that it is known and I know that it was apparently fixed. However it's fixed for me. So I need some help about getting to to work for me. And also as I've said, id rather disable the PIN on the SIM rather than simply saving it in NetworkManager.

A bug report is a description of something that does not behave as it is supposed to. Not knowing how to disable the PIN or not knowing how to work around an existing and confirmed bug is clearly something else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable PIN checking using the built in GSM modem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/244771/98375).

Comment: That looks promising, but how do I determine the path of the modem? After all it is inbuilt and I cannot unplug it.

Comment: I was able to find the device with `hwinfo`.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the popup, you can disable the PIN on your SIM card. As an alternative to using `gsmctl` as in the accepted answer, you can use [`qmicli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/qmicli.1.html). Assuming your PIN is 1234:

```
sudo apt-get install libqmi-utils
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-uim-get-pin-status
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-uim-set-pin-protection=PIN,disable,1234
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-uim-get-pin-status
```

(`qmicli` can also [disable PIN2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222006), should anyone need that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the PIN in the configuration, then network-manager won't ask for it again.

**Graphical Way**

Open Network-Connections, go to tab 'Mobile Broadband'

[image: Screenshot, Network-Connections]

Click 'Edit' and go again to the tab 'Mobile Broadband'

[image: Screenshot, Mobile Broadband]

Enter your PIN here, then it shouldn't ask for it again.

**Command-line**

This is an *alternative* to the way described above. No need to do both ways!

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

There open the configuration-file of your broadband with your favorite editor. In my case: `sudo gedit ./beeline` 
There should be a `[gsm]`-section, here you can add your PIN code `pin=1234`.
If the gsm-section does not exist add the following to the end of the file:

```
[gsm]
pin=1234
```

Comment: In 11.10 due to a bug it did ask for a pin if you had carried out the steps you have described. It was a known bug. Not sure how it is now, as I've disabled the PIN on the SIM card.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the comments under your questions carefully enough. Anyway: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: In Debian Stable I got this to work with NetworkManager version 0.9.4.0-10. I assume the bug is fixed now, and the fix is in Ubuntu a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one would take the sim card put it in a phone and change the pin code to 0000.
which effectively disabled the pin. I don't know  of any way  you can change the pin of a sim card through the 3g modem in your laptop somehow. But if you can that would be the way