# How to disable popup "SIM PIN Unlock Required"?

Tags: 12.10

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo W500 and this annoying popup keeps appearing on start up.

[image]

The text sais: "SIM PIN unlock required" and "The mobile broadband device 'Ericsson F3507g' requires a SIM PIN code before it can be used." (for search engines)

I do not plan on using this device and I just want to disable this popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same problem with my W520 on Ubuntu 14.04 (I don't want to use the device at all but I also don't want to add any special settings) and solved it by completely disabling mobile broadband:

- Enter the BIOS
- Navigate to `Security -> I/O Port Access`
- Set `Wireless WAN` to `Disabled`

No more popups.

Answer (score 5):

You have to know the PIN of the SIM if you want to disable PIN checking. There are two possibilities:

1) Put the SIM card into your **mobile phone**, enter the pin. Look for "disable PIN" in the settings of your mobile phone.

2) Use **gsmctl** as described [here](http://tech.valgog.com/2011/10/how-to-remove-sim-card-pin-from-your.html):

```
sudo apt-get install gsm-utils
sudo gsmctl -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -o unlock sc all 1234
```

where 1234 is the PIN. Check for the device path (ttyUSB*) with **dmesg** after plugging in the GSM modem. It should look similar to this:

```
[13274.395894] option 2-4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[13274.396084] usb 2-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Actually it is not a real *answer*. Because the user don't know him `PIN` number, so your method will never work for him. Also, the above answer will do the same as your information an more easy

Comment: I have a built-in SIM, how can I find its device name please?

Comment: @Sadi What do you mean by device name? If you are looking for the device in /dev/ you can try `hwinfo`

Comment: I mean device path. As I don't have a USB GSM modem, but a SIM card inserted into a slot, I think it should be something different than "/dev/ttyUSB0". How do I know that?

Comment: Have you checked `hwinfo` and `dmesg` for tokens like **gsm** or **modem**?

Comment: This is the only valid option to permanently remove the PIN code from the SIM card (without disabling it). And for those like me who have an integrated modem (not USB), I tried `/dev/ttyACM0` as shown in the linked blog post and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

For me, only `mmcli` works:

1. list modems

   ```
   mmcli -L
   ```
2. get path to sim

   ```
   mmcli -m "MODEM-NUMBER"
   ```
3. disable PIN

   ```
   mmcli -i "PATH-TO-SIM" --pin="PIN" --disable-pin
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Is the Mobile Broadband card removable, i.e. just a card? You could just pull it out then. Also, if you fire up Network Manager (Network Connection), and click the "Mobile Broadband" tab, you should be able to either Edit it, and tell it to never connect, or delete the connection altogether. Sorry, I do not have a mobile broadband card, so I cannot give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Tick mark on option `Automatically unlock this device`. You can disable it permenantly from making PIN disable. You can ask your provider to remove Pin of sim.

Comment: I do not know my PIN, as I have never used this card before.

Comment: When I tick "Automatically unlock this device" and successfully enter the PIN code, I still get the same prompt once in a while. I wonder why it fails to remember this?

Comment: Doing this will remember the pin for as long as the device is powered. As soon as you restart or put your laptop to sleep, it'll ask again. So this is quite useless, I'm not even sure what's the difference with this unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use your inbuilt 3G-modem you can disable it device:

Open in command-line `sudoedit /etc/rc.local` and before the line with `exit 0` add:

```
rfkill block wwan
```